# Are arguments in Ruby array?

Tags: ruby

[join](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-join) is used to convert an array to a string. In the following, `*names` is joined, and is output. Does this mean arguments are array?

```
def introduction( age, gender, *names)
  "Meet #{names.join(" ")}, who's #{age} and #{gender}"
end

puts introduction(28, "Male", "Sidu", "Ponnappa", "Chonira")
```

This outputs:

> Meet Sidu Ponnappa Chonira, who's 28 and Male

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass `*names` to `introduction` then you get a Ruby Array of `names`. The asterisk (`*`) means it's variable length. The `join` member of the `Array` class in Ruby converts each member of the array to String (if they are convertible) and concatenates them together using the parameter to `join` as a delimiter.

Note that all of the arguments to a method together do not form an Array. That is, `age`, `gender`, `*names` together are not passed in as an array but are simply separate arguments to the method.

Answer (score 2):

Here is code that shows what the *args ends up being, with examples of optional argument, greedy argument and required argument.

```
def something(name = 'Joe', *args, last_name)
  puts name, args, last_name
  puts args.inspect
  puts "Last name is #{last_name}"
end

something "one", 'Smith'

# >> one
# >> Smith
# >> []
# >> Last name is Smith
```

The * (splat) operator says to accept 0 or more arguments, and it **does not need to be the last** in the list. Now with named arguments, it would be surprising if it would, given that named arguments needs to be last, if I remember correctly.

The 0 or more arguments will be stored in an array.

You can use the code above to start making changes and explore this.

Comment: What is strong params?

Comment: I will let the [Ruby Rogues](http://ruby5.envylabs.com/episodes/432-episode-396-august-20th-2013/stories/3503-strong-params-by-example) answer that question.

Comment: @vgoff, you have mistaken *named parameters* (which are Ruby feature) and *strong parameters* (which are ActiveRecord feature).